# Не компиляция библиотеки в Pyinstaller

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

Как можно сделать так чтобы, Pyinstaller не компилировал пакет в exe, а сделать к нему обращение через папку (сделать динамическое подключение).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно. Вот оригинал: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74661699/12788763.
Я немного переделал код:
**main.py**

```
import sys
import importlib.util
import sys

def load_module(module_name, module_file):
    if spec:=importlib.util.spec_from_file_location(module_name, module_file):
        interface = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
        sys.modules[module_name] = interface
        spec.loader.exec_module(interface)
    globals()[module_name] = sys.modules[module_name]

load_module('my_module', 'modules/my_module/main.py')
load_module('my_module2', 'modules/my_module2/main.py')

print(my_module.f(5))
print(my_module2.f(5))

input('Enter to exit')
```

**my_module/main.py**

```
def f(n):
    return n**2
```

**my_module2/main.py**

```
def f(n):
    return n**3
```

При этом структура проекта будет такой:

```
│   main.exe
├───modules
│   ├───my_module
│   │       main.py
│   └───my_module2
│           main.py
```

---

P.S. Если вы импортируете модуль `A`, который использует модуль `B` (например, `requests` использует `urllib3`) - способ не сработает, если не переписать таким же образом импорты модуля `B`.

Comment: Не совсем это имел ввиду, создаю программку, которая использует модуль docxtpl (лицензия у него lgpl 2). По условиям этой лицензии должн быть открытый доступ к этому модулю. Хочу сделать так чтобы, моя программа создавалась в exe через Pyinstaller (или другой модуль), но чтобы остался видимым модуль docxtpl.

Comment: и чем, собственно, не подходит ? копируете файлы этого модуля и его зависимостей к вашему `exe` и используйте функцию подгрузки модуля из ответа к самому `docxtpl` и его зависимостям